# Concept name required

Tags: java

I can't remember the name of this concept.

```
  public interface MainInterface {
      public void method1();
      public void method2();
 }

  void testMethod() {
        methodMain(new MainInterface() {

            @Override
            public void method1() {
                System.out.println("This is method1");
            }

            @Override
            public void method2() {
                System.out.println("This is method2");
            }
        });
    }

   void methodMain(MainInterface mi) {
        mi.method1();
        mi.method2();
   }
```

- I create the instance of MainInterface without giving the name of object
- I implement the interface methods
- Then pass the instance with unknown name to methodMain.

What is this concept and how exactly it works?

Comment: For pointing out the "anonymous inner class" concept, you should change your sample code to create an anonymous `Comparator` or `Runnable` and use it for sorting or async execution. Pointing out the interface definition and its usage involves other (more advanced) concepts and makes the question a little ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created an instance of an [Anonymous Inner Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html) (i.e. a class without a name).

Comment: Exactly. And it works because the compiler analyses that and moves your anonymous code to an automatically named class member.

Answer (score 0):

The concept is referred to as [*callback*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29). In java, you only have callback interfaces, in other languages you can have callback functions.

As a design pattern, this concept is involved in the strategy pattern (as amit already mentioned).

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous classes is what you search.